# In Vue, how can I reference multiple similar elements from server rendered template?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `table` of number inputs for different products. Each row looks like this:

```
<tr>
 <td><input type="number" name=quantity1 value="0"></td>
</tr>
```

At the bottom, I'd like to show a sum of quantities based on what the user inputs on each row. All html code is server rendered and I only use Vue for the interactive part, so I'm not using `v-for` to generate the list on the client.

My question is: Is there a way to annotate the server template (or another technique) so that I can easily reference the input value of each row **with Vue** (aside from something like vanilla `querySelector`)? I imagine there must be something more in the lines of `v-model` that would perhaps collect all values in a data array or similar. Thanks!

Comment: If you're rendering the HTML server-side without `v-for`, then it sounds like you should be able to keep a count of the number of input rows. In that case, you should be able to use a data field with an array (let's call it `values_array`). Have the array populated with default values for each of the `n` input rows, then for a given `index` you can do `v-model="values_array[index]"`. A computed property can then be used to track the total sum of all of the array elements, or the sum may be calculated manually via a method invoked by a button click.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting strategy. The thing is, the Javascript is compiled with Webpack and comes from another file, so to populate the array with values I'd need to run some kind of loop inside a `mounted` callback to collect values from the html. I could use `refs`, or `data-` attributes, but I wonder if there's another way to do this with Vue. Probably not though.